# Number of objects created

Tags: java, memory-management

Today, I had the following question in exam:

```
String[] subjects=new String[10];
String subname="POPL-201617";
subjects[0]=subName;
subName=null;
```

1. How many objects are created?

   My answer: 11 objects will be created. 10 from the first statement and one is the string literal.
2. How many references to those objects exist after the code executes?

   My answer: There is one reference to "POPL-201617" in total.
3. Explain whether these objects are eligible for garbage collection.

   My answer: Since there is a reference to "POPL-201617", it is not eligible for garbage collection. Even if there was no reference, it is an interned string and hence, can't be garbage collected. Rest all are eligible for garbage collection.

I am concerned about the first statement. We're not passing any argument to the constructor of the String class. Will it form the objects or just space is allocated on the heap?

Also, my understanding says that subjects initially points to the base of the array. So, the first element initially had a reference. But since subjects[0] now refers to POPL, the no array element has any reference.

Am I correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're not creating *any* string objects in the first statement. You're only creating an array (one object). Every element of the array will be a null reference.

Comment: Hell. How did I miss it? There go 6 points.

Comment: Interned strings can be garbage collected under certain circumstances.

Comment: *One* object is created by executing the above code: the array. The literal was already created on classloading after having been pooled by the compiler. You aren't passing any arguments to the constructor of the `String` class because you aren't even calling the constructor of the `String` class in the first line. Nothing becomes eligible for GC by executing this code.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you missed was that `String[] subjects=new String[10]` created just one object of type `String[]`.